# Variable not being modified Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, variables

I'm really lost as to what is happening here.

I am basically trying to pass a variable between two classes but it doesn't even get to that point for one of these variables.

I have two Strings and two buttons declared.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *qm;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *m;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *mBtn;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *qmBtn;
```

I synthesise the strings..

```
@synthesize qm;
@synthesize m;
```

Initialise the strings...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    qm = @"0";
    m = @"0";
}
```

And these methods reassign the new variable based on the selected button on the view (I've definitely made sure to link the buttons to their corresponding variables and methods from the view)

```
- (IBAction)mPressed:(id)sender {
    m = @"1";



}

- (IBAction)qmPressed:(id)sender {
    qm = @"1";

    NSLog(@"This value%@", qm);
}
```

The NSLog prints the value 1, which is what I want

When the program enters the segue part. Things don't work as planned...

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Here:%@", qm);
    if([m  isEqualToString: @"1"]){

        QMMPOpViewController *mpOp = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSLog(@"test 1:%@",self.qm);
        mpOp.qm = self.qm;
        mpOp.selectedQuiz = self.selectedQuiz2;
        NSLog(@"This value2%@", qm);
        NSLog(@"This value3%@", m);

    }
       else if([qm  isEqualToString: @"1"]){
           QMMPOpViewController *mpOp = [segue destinationViewController];
           NSLog(@"test 2:%@",self.qm);
           mpOp.qm = self.qm;
           mpOp.selectedQuiz = self.selectedQuiz2;
           NSLog(@"This value2%@", qm);
           NSLog(@"This value3%@", m);
       }
    else{

    QMSPController *tableVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    tableVC.selectedQuiz = self.selectedQuiz2;
    }


}
```

I have changed the value of `qm`; the `NSLog` outputs the value 0 instead of the new variable, 1. So therefore `([qm  isEqualToString: @"1"])` is never called.

This is so simple yet it still doesn't work despite my attempts to debug the issue. The `m` value executes fine. Though identical in their means of operation. For some reason the other one does not.

Maybe I'm missing something blatantly obvious or basic. Or if someone could let me know what could possibly be going on here that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are modifying the correct property in the `IBAction` method?

Comment: @NSHeffalump Yes. The String property is `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *qm;`
and I am editing it with `qm = @"1";`

Comment: You don't really need that @synthesize, and I wonder if you're using a empty setter somehow.  Without @synthesize, you get accessor methods synthesized provided that you don't define either a setter or getter method.  And you are certainly mixing direct iVar access `qm` with getter `self.qm` -- you really ought to use the getter.  I worry one class is missing the synthesize and has a _qm iVar while the other's got a qm iVar.

Comment: @stevesliva The problem is currently all confined within the one class. It simply isn't keeping the changed value of qm but keeping m for some reason. I even tried your suggestions to no avail.

Comment: @stevesliva What I've discovered is that the `mBtn` is calling the prepare for segue where the `qmBtn` is not. Hence the reason why the variable is not being modified appropriately. You wouldn't happen to know why that is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Something wrong in the storyboard, I'd guess.  Storyboards aren't my thing, though.